# rewrite javascript that it marks different times

Tags: javascript

In my HTML I have different times not always time difference 15 minutes. it is possible to make so that (when 8:00 clock is automatically reads the ID and the next ID makes bold (example  8:00 clock ist neu and bolld is  next id with 8:02)
`

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
var minuteBin = currentMinute - (currentMinute % 15);
var idString = ""+currentHour+minuteBin;

console.log("Time =",currentHour,":",currentMinute,"bin =",minuteBin,"idString =",idString);

document.getElementById(idString).className = 'bold';
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="2145">
        <td>21:45</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2200">
        <td>22:00</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2215">
        <td>22:15</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table width="166">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>NISJA</td>
<td>OPERATORI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:50</td>
<td>BREST-TOURS-ZA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:15</td>
<td>HALIMAJ-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:50</td>
<td>DIDI-COMPANI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>08:20</td>
<td>DRINI-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>08:45</td>
<td>BASHKIMI-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>09:05</td>
<td>FIDANI-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>09:30</td>
<td>ZHUR-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>09:55</td>
<td>MIR-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:20</td>
<td>ATMAXHA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:35</td>
<td>ARBËRIA-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00</td>
<td>SHPEJTIMI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:20</td>
<td>SHARRI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:45</td>
<td>HALIMAJ-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>FATI-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:10</td>
<td>BREST-ZAPLLUZHË</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:35</td>
<td>JETA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:50</td>
<td>ERZA-ZAPLLUZHË</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13:05</td>
<td>DIDI-COMPANI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13:30</td>
<td>DARDANI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14:00</td>
<td>BASHKIMI-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14:30</td>
<td>ZHUR-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14:45</td>
<td>TOSA-ZAPLLUZHË</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14:55</td>
<td>NUHI-Q-GASHI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15:05</td>
<td>Op. nuk dihet</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15:20</td>
<td>Op. nuk dihet</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15:35</td>
<td>ATMAXHA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15:50</td>
<td>ARBËRIA-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16:10</td>
<td>SHPEJTIMI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16:25</td>
<td>MIR-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16:40</td>
<td>BRES TOUR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16:55</td>
<td>HALIMAJ-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17:15</td>
<td>SHPEJTIMI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17:35</td>
<td>SHARRI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17:55</td>
<td>JETA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18:15</td>
<td>BASHKIMI-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18:40</td>
<td>ZHUR-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18:55</td>
<td>TEUTA-MARKET</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19:15</td>
<td>BRES-TOU-ZAPLL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19:45</td>
<td>DARDANI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20:10</td>
<td>ERZA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't have IDs that being with Numbers! Prepend your IDs with something else to begin with (say `time`)

Comment: @somethinghere why not ? Seriously I am curious

Comment: In HTML 4, an ID couldn't start with a number. That restriction was removed in HTML 5.

Comment: How do I get it automatically makes the text down  the id bold

Comment: Thanks much @Quentin, was not aware

Comment: @AnirbanN `Note: Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.` - sorry I didnt know it was lifted, but still.

Comment: what is the best way to get it work how i want ? because in javascript I'm not so good

Comment: Do you call the JS after the element is added to the page? AKA is this code run at the bottom of the page, document ready, or window onload? What is the error in the console? The code should work.

Comment: the code hir works great. only it is limited only every 15 minutes, it exchanges the ID and makes it bold. but I need for different times

Comment: How can I do that. For example, now time is 8:00 clock it makes nechste ID Bold 08:03 .and then when the time is 8:03, he makes the bold nechste id as 08:09

Answer (score 0):

You want the next possible ID to light up, so we'll have to find out what that one is. Lets try the following:

First, get the current possible ID. You already have this. Except, you don't want to round this to 15. You want the current time so you can select any time you have an id for.

```
var currentTimeStamp = currentHour + '' + minutes;
```

Now we want to keep upping this id by 1 as long as it does not exist.
To prevent an infinite loop, also add a maximum amount we can count. If this id doesn't exist, `document.getElementById` will return `undefined`, which is `false`, so it will keep looping until either the `currentTimeStamp` is no longer smaller than our `stopCounting` value, or when `getElementById` is not `undefined` or `false` anymore. That result tells you the closest existing id.

```
var stopCounting = currentTimeStamp + 15;
while(
    !document.getElementById(currentTimeStamp) &&
    currentTimeStamp < stopCounting
){ 
    currentTimeStamp++;
}
```

The while loop can end in one of two ways:
1) We found an element
2) We reached the maximum value we want to try (15 in this case)
So check if the element exists by checking getElement again, and defining it as `false` if not.

```
var selectedId = document.getElementById(currentTimeStamp) || false;
```

The last bit is to add your class if it exists (and therefor doesn't evaluate to `false`), otherwise we'll log an error message.

```
if(selectedId){
    selectedId.className += "bold";
} else {
    console.log("Could not find an id within 15 minutes of now.");
}
```

This is the whole process to use in your case. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here, I have a slight feeling it's a complicated way to succeed. I think it might be better to use a `data-attribute` for this instead of an id, but okay.

Heres a fully functional snippet that searches for the next available id:

#### Updated

I've added a by-the-minute checker.

```js
var current = false;

function check(){
  var date     = new Date();
  var hours    = date.getHours();
  var minutes  = date.getMinutes();

  document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes;

  var maximum  = minutes + 15;

  while(
    !document.getElementById('q-' + minutes) &&
    minutes < maximum
  ) {
    minutes++;
  }

  var id = document.getElementById('q-' + minutes) || false;
  
  // Remove any existing selected classes:
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
  for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
    all.item(i).className = all.item(i).className.replace("selected", "");
  }
  
  if(id){
    id.className = "selected";
  }
  
  // Run the function every 60 seconds
  setTimeout(check, 1000 * 60);
  
}

// Start running the function
check();
```

```css
.selected { color: red }
```

```html
<div>Current time: <strong id="currentTime"></strong></div>
<br /><br />
<div id="q-0">The hour is coming up.</div>
<div id="q-15">A quarter past is coming up.</div>
<div id="q-30">Half past is coming up.</div>
<div id="q-45">A quarter to is coming up.</div>
```

Comment: which is super only the problem is I have to adjust the different times, for example 18:19, next ID 18:22 18:33 NEXT ID, I need something that approved via the ID, and if the time in ID was overtaken automatically the nechste ID Bold that's my problem

Comment: This works to select the right ID, it just only does this on pageload. Wrap the whole thing in a `setInterval(function(){ /* code here (/ }, 1000 * 60);` to perform a check every minute and update the next id (you will have to remove the `active` class.

Comment: @TonTonii I have updated my snippet to keep checking. It will also update the time. If this doesn't help I cant do anything.

Comment: I have to question the table added, this table needs to be highlighted when the time was cross over a number nechste be marked

Comment: when the time is over the stands on the table to select the next

Comment: Then count backwards if you want the one _before_ it, instead of counting forward (switch `++` with `--`)